# how interrupta thread that use blocking call in a looper

Tags: android, multithreading

hi mate i have a thread that use looper. in the looper when he receive message , he call a blocking method (style read socket). How can can write method StopThread to stop this thread to terminate him ? have i to call quit on Handler or interrupt to thread ? 
this is the code:

```
    class LooperThread extends Thread {
          public Handler mHandler;

          public void run() {
              Looper.prepare();

              mHandler = new Handler() {
                  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                  try{
                 blocking call read
                  }catch(Interrupet Exception e) {  }
                  }
              };

              Looper.loop();
          }
public void stopThread(){    ??? }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call

```
thread.interrupt()
```

to interrupt the thread.
Edit: You will have to post a runnable on the thread.

```
looperthread.handler.postrunnable(new Runnable(){

run(){
  Looper.myLooper().quit();
}
});
```

Comment: and also interrupet the loop ? i want to interrupt the thread not only the read. i think with interrupt i only stop read

Comment: Then you will also have to use  Looper.myLooper().quit() inside the thread

Comment: what is my looper and what means i have to post runnable ? my thread have method run

Comment: ok @nandeesh but if the thread is blocking on the read, the runnable that i have post with your code is never executed.. how can solve this last problem ? very thank if you solve this last problem i check your answer with best answer :)

Comment: greatz i think whit this method is all ok !